# Apex/Visualforce: multiline IF statement in HTML

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, html

Can I write a multiline if statement in Apex/Visualforce HTML?

Something like (definitely pseudocode):

```
<apex if (condition)>
  <strong>This HTML.</strong>
<apex else>
  <strong>This is the false HTML.</strong>
<apex end>
```

**Update**

It seems like the answers here don't work, i.e. neither this:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Lead.Credit__c > 0)}">
  <tr>
    <td>Credit</td>
    <td>{!Lead.Credit__c}</td>
  </tr>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Nor this work:

```
<apex:variable var="v" value="1" rendered="{!IF(Lead.Credit__c > 0)}">
  <tr>
    <td>Credit</td>
    <td>{!Lead.Credit__c}</td>
  </tr>
</apex:variable>
```

Does it have to be a boolean value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use like below

```
<apex:outputtext value="!IF(ISNULL(Eslot.sEvent), 'Free', IF(Eslot.sEvent.Appointment_Type__c == 'Personal', 'Pers', 'Fill'))}"/>
```

else

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered = "{! If(m.Name=='sai' ,true,false) }">
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered = "{! If(m.Name=='sam' ,true,false) }">
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered = "{! If(m.Name=='test1' ,true,false) }">
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Addition to above

If you are using html elements and want to hide based on conditions

```
<div style= "display: {!If(m.Name=='sai' ,'none','') }">
</div>
<div  style= "display: {! If(m.Name=='sam' ,'none','') }">
</div >
<div  rendered = "display:{! If(m.Name=='test1' ,'none','') }">
</div >
```

Comment: That's a single line. I need to fit in multiple lines of HTML.

Comment: `!IF(ISNULL(Eslot.sEvent), 'Free', IF(Eslot.sEvent.Appointment_Type__c == 'Personal', 'Pers', 'Fill'))}` this is multiple conditions

Comment: Use rendered tag as I have outlined

Answer (score 7):

Visualforce has IF() function

```
<strong>
<apex:outputtext value="{!IF(condition, 'This HTML.', 'This is the false HTML.')}"/>
 </strong>
```

In apex we have if and else statments .You can use rendered tag as well to render based on boolean getter from apex

```
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!booleantrue}"
  <strong>This HTML.</strong>
 </apex:outputPanel>
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(booleantrue)}"
   <strong>This is the false HTML.</strong>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `apex:outputPanel`

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!someBooleanFlg}">
    <strong>This HTML.</strong>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(someBooleanFlg)}">
    <strong>This is the false HTML.</strong>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

OR `apex:variable`

```
<apex:variable var="v" value="1" rendered="{!someBooleanFlg}">
    <strong>This HTML.</strong>
</apex:variable>
<apex:variable var="v" value="1" rendered="{!NOT(someBooleanFlg)}">
    <strong>This is the false HTML.</strong>
</apex:variable>
```

The different is `apex:outputPanel` will output `<span>` tag and `apex:variable` will not.